# Linear dependence of a set of linear combinations

Tags: linear-algebra

If the elements of $A=\{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\}$ are linear combinations of the elements of another set, say $B=\{b_1,b_2,...,b_n\}$, then how can I show that $A$ is not linearly independent?

Comment: Is $B$ linearly independent?

Comment: Are you sure that number of elements in $A$ and $B$ are equal?

Comment: Yes, $n(A)=n(B)$, but it was not mentioned if $B$ is dependent or not.

Answer (score 5):

You can't because that statement is not always true. Counterexample: If $B = \{ (1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1) \}$, then $A = \{ (1,1,0), (1,0,1), (0,1,1) \}$ is a set of linear combinations of the elements of $B$, but $A$ is linearly independent.

Answer (score -1):

As it was said before, **A** must not be lineary dependent. The easy way to define it is to make a matrix, where coefficients are the coefficients from linear combinations of vectors from **A** through **B**, and then calculate its determinant. If det = 0 $ \Rightarrow$ **A** is not linearly independent. For example, If B={(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)}, A={(1,1,1),(1,0,1),(0,1,0)} then  matrix is \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, it's det = 0, so A is not lineary independent

Comment: You give an example; an example is not a proof. If you don't convert it into a proof, I am sure that your post will get deleted pretty soon.

Comment: @AlexM. The art of prediction is a difficult one.